# Warning with boost: Integer constant is too large for its type

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to store a 128 bit value into a uint128_t.

```
uint128_t CK1= 0x517cc1b727220a94fe13abe8fa9a6ee0;
```

The above is clearly less than 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, however when i compile i get the this:  warning: integer constant is too large for its type. I get the same warning when I try int128_t.

I was trying to implement an encryption algorithm and that required a 128 bit value to be stored in a variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp> 
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
int main()
{
    uint128_t CK1= 0x517cc1b727220a94fe13abe8fa9a6ee0;

    return 0;
}
```

Grateful for any help! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the preprocessor directive `BOOST_HAS_INT128` set?
Also you could share some additional info about your compiler and boost build options.

Comment: No. Sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: I am using g++ 4.9.2 and boost 1.59.0. I tried a smaller number like 0x52, that did not give a warning. But I need to store this 128 bit number.

Comment: Sorry! I should've included it before.

Comment: It seems that each digit is being represented by 8 bits when 4 are enough. Weird.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/limits/limits32.html

Maybe this will help you

Comment: Thanks everyone. This question has been answered before. I broke the number up into four 32 bit chunks. Used left shifts and addition after that.